# Clojure iterate 2d array and add quotes to each element

Tags: arrays, clojure

I am struggling to achieve this in Clojure and the examples I have found online aren't exactly providing me with a suitable solution.

Given a data set:

```
[[foo bar hello]
 [hello foo bar]
 [bar hello foo]]
```

However this array can be of any length `n`

I want to be able to return something that looks like this from a function:

```
 [["foo" "bar" "hello"]
  ["hello" "foo" "bar"]
  ["bar" "hello" "foo"]]
```

I have been looking into using `walk` but I am not fully sure how to apply the solutions.

The data must remain as shown above, its not possible to return a `map` and use that (not without rewriting a hell of a lot of the application).

Comment: I don't really get what has to be done here.

Comment: I need to append `""` to each element as the data is getting imported to another application which needs `""` around elements.

Comment: `(map (fn [row] (map (fn [cell] (i-dont-remember-how-to-add-quotes-but--it-should-be-easy cell) row) data-set)` is not working here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(println v)
;; [[foo bar hello] [hello foo bar] [bar hello foo]]

(println (vec (map (fn [inner] (vec (map #(str "\"" % "\"") inner))) v)))
;; [["foo" "bar" "hello"] ["hello" "foo" "bar"] ["bar" "hello" "foo"]]
```

**EDIT**: Use `mapv` to avoid `vec` calls:

```
(println (mapv (fn [inner] (mapv #(str "\"" % "\"") inner)) v))
;; [["foo" "bar" "hello"] ["hello" "foo" "bar"] ["bar" "hello" "foo"]]
```

Comment: You just mean `(mapv str inner)`, not `(mapv #(str "\"" % "\"") inner)`. The latter creates a string with actual quotes in it, as opposed to a string whose contents are (for example) the three characters `f` `o` `o`. You would see this if you simply let the repl print the result; but the `println` function is obscuring it.

Comment: Thanks, @amalloy, I had the impression that the OP really wanted the actual quote characters --- take a look at his comment clarifying his own question, above. But of course I may be misunderstanding the requirement.